# Merge trashed element with existing one

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce2, merge, element

Is there any way to merge trashed elements with an existing element? I'm creating a custom restore action so you can merge a trashed (commerce) Product with an existing one. The mergeElementsByIds function is failing because it uses the getElementById function which ignores trashed elements. Is there any work around?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/pull/4404

You can now delete objects that implement ElementInterface using this method:

```
craft\services\Elements::mergeElements()
```